# closest/next div selecting jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <button class="popup" id="$row[0]"></button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>



 <div class="details">
   <div id="section-2">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here goes JQuery script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.popup').click(function () {
      // something like this : $(this).next(".details").dialog('open');
        $('.details').dialog('open');
        });
      });
    });
```

I want to dialog closest/next div with class details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `details` element is the next sibling of the `table` element, so use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the table ancestor of the `button` then use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the `details` element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.popup').click(function () {
        // something like this : $(this).next(".details").dialog('open');
        $(this).closest('table').next('.details').dialog('open');
    });
});
```